# Probability Question. Expected Value.

Tags: probability

A game consists of rolling two dice. The sum of the two faces is a positive integer between 2 and 12. For each such a value, you win an amount of money as shown in the table below.

```
                         Score 2 3 4  5  6  7  8 9 10 11 12
                         $ won 4 6 8 10 20 40 20 10 8  6  4
```

Compute the expected value of this game.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What is your definition of expected value?

Comment: This is DEFINITELY a game I want to play!!  Why won't casino's do this??  ha ha!

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$\mathbb{E} = \sum_i P(X_i) \cdot X_i$.

$X_i$ is the money won.

What is the probability of getting $k$ called $\mathbb{P}(X = k)$ after rolling two dices?

Answer (score 0):

The big thing here is computing the probability of the sum of two dice.  PackSciences provided the mechanism for the calculation.  Now consider the probability of the sum of two die.  For example, if you roll a 4, you could have rolled the following;

$$\{(1,3), (2,2), (3,1)\}$$

Note here $(1,3)$ represents the first die being a 1 and the second one being a 3.  Also note that $(1,3)\neq(3,1)$.  Now, how many possible outcomes can you have?  You have $6\times 6=36$ different die roll combinations and so the probability that you roll a sum of 4 would be

$$P(sum=4)=\frac{3}{36}=\frac{1}{12}$$

Hopefully you can take it from here...

Answer (score -1):

```
First consider a random variable X, where X = the sum of the faces. 

Then, X's range must be {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}

The probability mass function, denoted p(x) of this random variable is shown below:

    p(2) = 1/36
    p(3) = 1/18
    p(4) = 1/12
    p(5) = 1/9
    p(6) = 5/36
    p(7) = 1/6
    p(8) = 5/36
    p(9) = 1/9
    p(10) = 1/12
    p(11) = 1/18
    p(12) = 1/36

    Now let a new random variable Y, denote the amount of earnings. 
    Y can take on the values {4,6,8,10,20,40}

    Y = 4, if X = 2 or X = 12
    Y = 6, if X = 3 or X = 11
    Y = 8, if X = 4 or X = 10
    Y = 10, if X = 5 or X = 9
    Y = 20, if X = 6 or X = 8
    Y = 40, if X = 7
```

Therefore **E[Y] = 4(2/36) + 6(4/36) + 8(6/36) + 10(8/36) + 20(10/36) + 40(6/36) = 16.67**

Answer (score -2):

Find the probability of getting each score.  For example P(2) = 1/36 (1+1 only so 1/6*1/6) and P(3) = 2/36 (2+1, 1+2 so 1/6*1/6 + 1/6*1/6). Then find the sum of each probability multiplied by its respective winnings, e.g. ((1/36)*4 + (2/36)*6 +...) to get the expected value.

A probability distribution table of winnings (r) and P(X = r) would be useful for these calculations.